# position().top inconsistencies when (zoom < 1)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a window of fixed position with horizontal and vertical scroll. And using position.top() to find the particular position of the div.

```
 var position = anchor.position().top;
```

But when zoom is 1 or >1 then it is working totally fine.
But when zoom is <1 then there are inconsistencies.

Example [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x36Rm/49/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to subtract the position of inner content

```
var position = anchor.position().top - $('.innercontent').position().top;
```

Checkout this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MasterVivek/x36Rm/52/)